# How can I place all children of document.body into a wrapper?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page, which contains a few different children in the body. I want the body to be the parent of only a single wrapper element, which will contain all of the previous children of the body. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Ah, now we have a question. You'd create a new element, then one by one append each child of `document.body` to that new element, then finally append the element to `document.body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move all child nodes of the body to a new element, then append the element to the body, e.g.

```
function wrapAll() {
  var el, div = document.createElement('div');
  while (el = document.body.firstChild) {
    div.appendChild(el);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

Call the function after the page loads:

```
window.onload = wrapAll;
```

If you don't care about IE 8 (and you should because it still has about 20% user share), you can use the more concise:

```
function wrapAll() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  [].slice.call(document.body.childNodes).forEach(function(node){div.appendChild(node)});
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
```

However I think the first is a better choice for compatibility and maintainability (and it's probably faster).

Note that the reason the second won't work in IE 8 is that it will not allow passing of host objets to built–in methods as *this*, you can't fix that with a polyfill, shim, monkey patch or whatever.

#### Edit

Following on from Squint's comment, you can also use *querySelectorAll* to skip the use of *slice* **if** there are no text nodes to consider:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.id = 'foo';
[].forEach.call(document.body.querySelectorAll('*'), function(node){div.appendChild(node)});
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

and since *forEach* will require a shim in IE8, passing a host object as *this* is fine. Note that the querySelector API is only partially supported in IE 8 and not at all in IE 7.

Comment: A little shorter and faster if you bypass `.slice()`, plus since `.forEach()` will have been shimmed, it'll work in IE8 since IE8 does allow host objects as `this` for user-defined functions: `[].forEach.call(document.body.childNodes, function(node){div.appendChild(node)});`

Comment: *slice* is required because the NodeList returned by *getElementsByTagName* is live and members are being removed so it's a moving target if passed directly to *forEach*. *querySelectorAll* can be used as it returns a static NodeList, it's not supported in IE7 and lower.

Comment: Yep, good point about the live list. `qSA` would work if there are no text nodes to be moved. Better off just slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are meaning to do this with JavaScript after the page loads, here's how (using jQuery):

```
var $wrapper = $('<div>');
var $children = $('body').contents();
$children.appendTo($wrapper);
$wrapper.appendTo('body');
```

In a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y6f6ht8n/1/

Comment: I was looking for pure JavaScript, but this works too!